# .htaccess RewriteRule issue

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns

I have a domain at OVH that links to my EC2 instance like this:
www.mysite.com --> 12.34.56.78/folder/
So everytime I type "www.mysite.com" in my address bar I end up on my website but the URL has been replaced to "12.34.56.78/folder/".

I'm currently trying to tweak a .htaccess file at the root of my server but it doesn't seem to work...
Here is the content of the file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/ [L]
```

Maybe I'm not looking at the right solution... Anyway if you can help me, I'll be grateful!
Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a couple of things that I added below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mysite\.com$ 
#$1 will include the original URI in the redirect, 301 for permanent
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I tried your code and when I type "www.mysite.com", I end up to: `http://12.34.56.78/opt/bitnami/apps/mysite/htdocs/^http://www.mysite.com/` :/

Comment: Forget what I said. Cleaned Firefox's cache and this ugly URL disappeared. However, now the routing seems to be: www.mysite.com --> 12.34.56.78/path --> www.mysite.com which leads nowhere (Firefox tells me that the redirection is not correct). Maybe it's a DNS issue at OVH. What do you think?

Comment: It was indeed a DNS issue. Just had to bind the A record for www.mysite.com to the Elastic IP of my EC2 instance!